# Costum text Telerik button

Tags: css, button, telerik

I have this Telerik Rad button

```
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" Text="Overview 112" Width="110px" Skin="Default"></telerik:RadButton>
```

I would like to customize part of the text and I have no idea if it's possible.
The end result should be "Overview" and the "112" highlight with some color.

Comment: Unless the text can be split into two elements this is not  possible.

Comment: I can split it <span>Overview</span>112

Comment: then you have something to select with CSS. I'm not familiar with Telerik but  the output HTML/CSS would be useful in a [mcve]

Comment: Your tip help me out to get there! @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with this solution. Please let me know if there is a better one

```
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" Text="Overview 112" Width="110px" Skin="Default">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                        <span>Overview</span>
                        <span style="color:red;">112</span>
                   </ContentTemplate>
```